# Find largest possible number less than Y

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

Re-arrange the number `X` and find the greatest possible number that is less than or equal to `Y`. If that is not possible then return `-1`.
Also, we should not have leading zeros for the generated output

**Example:**

```
X = 2851
Y = 8774
```

**Ans:**

```
8521
```

**Explanation:** 8521 is less than or equal to 8774 and it is the largest possible number.

This is the code I tried:

```
public String process(long X, long Y) {
 if(X > Y) return "-1";
 char[] arr = (""+X).toCharArray();
 Arrays.sort(arr);
 String s = new String(arr);
 s = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
 long x1 = Long.parseLong(s);
 if(x1 <= Y) return "" + x1;
 return "=1";
}
```

My approach is not correct as I am checking for the largest possible number always for the given digits in X. What is the correct approach to solve this program?

Another sample test case that fails with my program is:

**Example:**

```
X = 12222
Y = 21111
```

**Expected Ans:**

```
12222
```

Comment: Hint: Build a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with number of occurrences as value from the original number.

Comment: @SomeDude, what is the next step once TreeMap is created, lets say [{1,1}, {2,1}, {5,1}, {8,1}] for the first example

Comment: One thing to point out is that your first statement `if(X > Y) return "-1";` is incorrect.  Consider `x = 9231;
 y = 2314`.  `X` is greater than `Y` but  `2139` satisfies the requirements as stated.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, we should not have leading zeros for the generated output. I will update my post to add that condition.

Answer (score 2):

I'd break both numbers down to digits, and then for each digit of `y`, look for the greatest (remaining) digit of `x` that is not greater than it. In each step, if no such digit is found, `-1` can be returned.

```
public static long process(long src, long max) {
    long result = 0L;
    List<Long> srcDigits = getDigits(src);
    List<Long> maxDigits = getDigits(max);
    for (Long maxDigit : maxDigits) {
        Optional<Long> digit = 
            srcDigits.stream().filter(d -> d <= maxDigit).max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        if (digit.isEmpty()) {
            return -1L;
        }
        long srcDigit = digit.get();
        result *= 10;
        result += srcDigit;
        srcDigits.remove(srcDigit);
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<Long> getDigits(long num) {
    List<Long> digits = new LinkedList<>();
    while (num > 0) {
        digits.add(0, num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the time complexity for this approach, can you please provide that also

Comment: @learner for every digit of Y, you go over all the (remaining) digits of X. This is O(n^2), where n is the number of digits

Answer (score 1):

The idea introduced in the [answer by @Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74837713/17949945) can be enhanced by reducing the number of iterations.

We can create an array `int[]` of size `10` representing frequencies of each digit in the number `x`. It would eliminate the need of performing removal on the list which has a cost of **O(n)** like in the linked answer (instead the corresponding element would be decremented in **O(1)**). Also, the size of the array of frequents is less than the maximum possible number of digits in the `long` number. These advantages would be more significant if `x` and `y` would be represented as `BigInteger` or numeric `String`s.

```
public static String process(long x, long y) {
    
    int[] target = toArray(y);
    
    int[] frequencies = getFrequencies(x);
    int[] result = new int[target.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        int nextDigit = getIndex(frequencies, target[i]); // performs at most 10 iterations
        
        if (nextDigit == -1) return "-1";
        
        result[i] = nextDigit;    // O(1)
        frequencies[nextDigit]--; // O(1)
    }
    
    return toString(result);
}

public static int getIndex(int[] freq, int digit) {
    int nextDigit = -1;
    for (int i = digit; i > 0; i--) {
        if (freq[i] > 0) {
            nextDigit = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return nextDigit;
}

public static int[] toArray(long num) {
    
    return LongStream.iterate(num, n -> n > 0, n -> n / 10)
        .map(n -> n % 10)
        .collect(
            ArrayDeque<Long>::new,
            Deque::offerFirst,
            Collection::addAll
        )
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(Long::intValue)
        .toArray();
}

public static int[] getFrequencies(long num) {
    int[] freq = new int[10];
    long cur = num;
    while (cur != 0) {
        freq[(int) (cur % 10)]++;
        cur /= 10;
    }
    return freq;
}

public static String toString(int[] arr) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(process(2851, 8774));
}
```

*Output:*

```
8521
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `Y`, and each iteration look on X and find the greater possible digit in the remains digits in `X` that is less than or equal to `Y[i]`, if found take it and place it in `results[i]` (don’t forget to remove it from `X`), if not - return false.

Comment: This shall work only if the number of given digits and the number of digits in the least number are equal.